# How can I avoid always having to use `eval 'ssh-agent -s'`

Tags: bash, ssh, sshd, ssh-agent

I can't figure out why everytime I ssh back into my server I always have to start my ssh agent with the command `eval 'ssh-agent -s'` followed by `ssh-add <my_key.pem>` in order to successfully ssh from my server. I have placed this in my .bashrc but obviously I'm missing something and don't want to always have to initialize that each time I log in.

Comment: Maybe a [ssh-reagent](https://gist.github.com/akabos/4266975) script may help you?

Comment: thanks alot but this didn't help. perhaps I'm not using it correctly. I added it to my .bashrc but still get `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.` after running `ssh-add -L` after logging out.

Comment: You need to call the ssh-reagent() function (the gist only define it). There need also already a ssh-agent running.

Comment: Thanks again for this. I called it from my bashrc and seems to work now but i noticed a ton of ssh-agent processes running after that. Is there a way to just re-use same process?

Comment: Are you sure, that the the ssh-agent did not run previously? The ssh-reagent script does not start new ones.

Answer (score 3):

As @Jakuje said, using Forward Agent and using a key on your local, secure machine is better.

However, if you need to do what you say, use a tool such as `keychain` (github.com/funtoo/keychain) or `ssh-find-agent` (github.com/wwalker/ssh-find-agent ( I wrote the latter, and many still use it, but I have since switched to using the former ).  Both of these tools look for running gpg or ssh agents and connectyour environment up to them for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe much more secure and useful is to `ForwardAgent` from your workstation, than having some keys on some server and fiddle during each login with agent reinitialization.

You can simply add to your `~/.ssh/config` for appropriate host (or use `-A` switch to `ssh` command):

```
ForwardAgent yes
```

Add the local key to your local agent and you don't have to care if you use it locally or remotely.

---

You also didn't mention if it is password protected key, but I assume no, if you put it into `.bashrc`. Much easier way would be also to specify the path to key in your `~/.ssh/config` on server (if you want to have it on server) like this:

```
IdentityFile <my_key.pem>
```

again for specific host or globally.

Comment: I wonder what I did.... I had this issue when I set up ssh for my github account. Then I set up ssh for my digital ocean droplet and after doing ssh-copy-id, ssh-add, and then connecting to my webserver, the issue went away. I just restarted my computer and miraculously I don't have to start the agent any more. WEIRD

Comment: Not my choice cause I have hundreds of repos and do not put them to my ssh config ~/.ssh/config

Answer (score 0):

if you are encountering this with git pushes,setting git remote to match the settings in your .ssh/config should do the trick..

```
git remote add alice git@gitolite-as-alice:whatever.git
```

.ssh/config

```
Host gitolite-as-alice <-- matches git remote above
HostName git.company.com
User git
IdentityFile /home/whoever/.ssh/id_rsa.alice
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: Not my choice cause I have hundreds of repos and do not put them to my ssh config ~/.ssh/config